# Sum of List of tuple with same values and convert to dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

## Approach 1:

```
def get_dict(lists):
    lists.sort()
    summing=0
    value=''
    mydict={}
    for i in my_list:
        print(i)
        if (value in i[0]):
            summing = summing+i[1]
            mydict[i[0]] = summing
            value = i[0]
        else:
            summing = i[1]
            value = i[0]
    print(mydict)
```

## Approach 2:

```
def get_dict(mylists):
    d={}
    for item in my_list:
        if item[0] in d.keys():
            d[item[0]] = d.get(item[0])+item[1]
        else:
            d[item[0]] = item[1]
    
    print(d)
```

## Input

my_list = [('a',1), ('b',2), ('b',3), ('a',5), ('c',20), ('a',15), ('c',40)]

get_dict(my_list)

## Output

{'a': 21, 'b': 5, 'c': 60}

Comment: What's your question? Please don't name variables `sum`, it overwrites a builtin.

Comment: Using a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict): `d = defaultdict(int); for a,b in my_list: d[a] += b`

Comment: Thanks for your comment, made the edit and added another approach

Comment: I didn't want to use default dict as the output return type changes to ---->defaultdict(int, {'a': 21, 'b': 5, 'c': 60})

Comment: You can just `return dict(d)` to return a dictionary.

Comment: Thanks! I wanted to propose the solution, return or non-returning function is programmer's choice.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to check if the key already exists or not.

```
my_list = [('a',1), ('b',2), ('b',3), ('a',5), ('c',20), ('a',15), ('c',40)]                       

dic = dict()                                                                                       

for  i in my_list: 
    if i[0] not in dic: 
        dic[i[0]] = i[1] 
    else: 
        dic[i[0]] += i[1] 

dic
# {'a': 21, 'b': 5, 'c': 60}
```